Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit - Swift 6 migration issue
I am migrating our app to Swift 6, and I get this error:

Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture
semantics explicit

Then if I add 'self', I get:

(redundantSelf) Insert/remove explicit self where applicable.

I haven't shared the code because the two images are quite explicit.
I am using Xcode 16.0 with Swift 6.
Can anyone help with this?
Error implicit use of self.

Warnings to remove the self.

